# how to call a ERC20 contract fucntion inside ERC721 contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, erc20, erc721

what I am trying to accomplish is calling a function defined in ERC20 contract from ERC721 contract as shown below, specifically `transferFrom` function from ERC20 contract inside the same function in ERC721.

This does not compile.
what it ultimately does is that everytime a erc721 NFT transfer occurs, royalty is tranferred to the creator in the form of erc20 tokens.

```
import "./myToken.sol" as erc20contract //This is my ERC20 contract

contract ERC721 is ERC721Interface, myToken {
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public payable {

        address addr_owner = ownerOf(_tokenId);

        require(
            addr_owner == _from,
            "_from is NOT the owner of the token"
        );

        require(
            _to != address(0),
            "Transfer _to address 0x0"
        );

        address addr_allowed = allowance[_tokenId];
        bool isOp = operators[addr_owner][msg.sender];

        require(
            addr_owner == msg.sender || addr_allowed == msg.sender || isOp,
            "msg.sender does not have transferable token"
        );


        //transfer : change the owner of the token
        tokenOwners[_tokenId] = _to;
        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(1);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(1);

        //reset approved address
        if (allowance[_tokenId] != address(0)) {
            delete allowance[_tokenId];
        }

        erc20contract.transferFrom(_to, nftInfo[_from].creator, 10); // This is what I'd like to achieve
        {
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _tokenId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I've just noticed your contract seemingly implements both the `ERC721` and `ERC20` standards. You'll [need to decide on one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/85349), but using composition (as I've shown below) might be sufficient to provide all the necessary functionality you're after.

---

Unless I'm missing something, you only seem to lack an actual instance of your ERC20 token. For example:

```solidity
contract YourToken is ERC721 {
  ERC20 private immutable token;

  constructor(ERC20 t) {
    token = t;
  }

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public payable {
    // Your code here.
    token.transferFrom(_from, _to, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Tadeg, Thanks. But I need to separately implement both ERC20 and 721 standards as my dapp allows users to buy erc20 tokens with Eth and mint/trade 721 NFT tokens.